# max of absolute value of log convex, concave or neither?

Tags: convex-analysis

$$f(x)=\exp\left\{\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\left|\log(a_i^Tx)\right| \right\}$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\operatorname{dom} f = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^m_+ \mid a_i^Tx>0, i = 1,\ldots,n \}$

I know that $|\log(a_i^Tx)|$ is neither convex or concave but is this also the case for $f$? If so how can I show that?

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. When you write `\text{exp}` rather than `\exp`, then instead of $3\exp5$ or $3\exp(5)$ you see $3\text{exp}5$ or $3\text{exp}(5).$ Notice that in $\exp5$ and $\exp(5),$  coded as `\exp5` and `\exp(5)` respectively, there is more space to the right of $\exp$ in one of these expressions than in the other. With `\text{exp}` you don't get context-dependent spacing.

Comment: Notice that with `\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}` you see $\displaystyle \max_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ (when it's in a "displayed" setting) whereas with `\text{max}_{i=1,\ldots,n}` you see $\displaystyle \text{max}_{i=1,\ldots,n}. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\exp$ is a monotone transformation, $\exp(\max_i y_i) = \max_i \exp(y_i)$ for any vector $y$. Therefore:

$$f(x) = \exp\left\{\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\left|\log(a_i^Tx)\right| \right\} = \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} \exp\left\{\left|\log(a_i^Tx)\right| \right\}$$

Since the maximum of convex functions is convex, it suffices to check if $g_i(x) = \exp\left\{\left|\log(x)\right| \right\}$ is convex. You can either plot a graph to convince yourself it's convex, or you can formally prove it.

Comment: @aTa perhaps we look at a different plot, what is the base of the logarithm?

Comment: you say you 'cannot use pointwise maximum', but the functions are *identical*

Comment: i said 'cannot use pointwise maximum' if the inner functions are not convex. but if the log's base is less than or equal to $e$ then pointwise maximum should work